# No instance for (Show (Double -> Double))

Tags: haskell

I have the following code which uses Newton's method to approximate the square root of some number. The problems is that when I run it, I get an error..**What is wrong and how can I fix it?**

```
newtonRootSequence :: Double -> [Double]
newtonRootSequence d = newtonSequenceGenerator d 1

newtonSequenceGenerator :: Double -> Double -> [Double]
newtonSequenceGenerator d xn = nxplus1 : newtonSequenceGenerator d nxplus1
    where nxplus1 =  (xn + d / xn) / 2

newtonRoot:: Double -> Double -> Double
newtonRoot d epsilon = head ([xs !! index | index <- [1..((length xs) - 1)], (xs !! index) - (xs !! index - 1) <= epsilon]
    where xs = newtonRootSequence d
```

Error:

```
 <interactive>:2:1: error:
        * No instance for (Show (Double -> Double))
            arising from a use of `print'
            (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
        * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Running it should be like the following:

> $newtonRoot 35

Comment: What query did you write? It looks to me that you wrote something like `newtonRoot 3`.

Comment: Where are you printing? You seem to be trying to print a partially applied function.

Comment: Did you notice the message "(maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell all function are curryfied, so, your function

```
newtonRoot:: Double -> Double -> Double
```

the are "hidden parenthesis":

```
newtonRoot:: Double -> (Double -> Double)
```

if you provide one argument `newtonRoot 35` you have

```
(newtonRoot 35) :: Double -> Double
```

and a function `f :: Double -> Double` is not instance of Show type class

You need to finally provide the last argument to your function value:

```
(newtonRoot 35 2) :: Double
```

Double can me shown

Answer (score 3):

`newtonRoot` takes two arguments, a `d` and an `epsilon`. You didn't supply an `epsilon`. Try

```
> newtonRoot 35 0.1
```

instead.

There are other errors, too, but this should get you started down the debugging path.